# What can replace a dryboard in a cold, moist house?

Tags: drywall, humidity

The dryboards (?) in my summer house are starting to crumble. They have been here for at least 50 years, without any issues, but ever since no-one is living there permanently (4 years ago), they are falling apart.

It looks like humidity-related to me, and I am afraid that if I replace with the same kind of dryboard, I'll get the same thing quickly. Is there anything more appropriate for this context?

Inside the house, I measure:

Winter: 7°C / 44°F - 50 to 60% relative humidity
Summer: 20°C / 68°F - 60% relative humidity

[image: Picture of the wall]
[image: Picture of the wall]

Edit: Layout to better understand

[image]

Comment: You say dryboards do you mean *drywall* or *Sheetrock*?  In the second photo It looks like it may be  plaster.

Comment: I like how those wires just sprout from the wall.

Comment: @Willk They're actually copper pipes for hot and cold water :)

Comment: @AlaskaMan I do not have a clue. Those were installed by my (great?) grand-father at least 50 years ago, and as you can guess, I am not, at all, knowledgeable enough to figure out what it is

Comment: Hmm.  If there are old water pipes behind that wall that might account for the damage you see.

Comment: @Willk the pipe runs straight through the wall, but does not really run "behind" it. I have added a drawing to clarify how it works